# MQRC_OBJECT_ALREADY_EXISTS error code 2100

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am Using IBM WebSphere MQ. Whenever simultaneous users log in to the IBM MQ, when the second user comes and try to access the getqueue they receive `2100  0x00000834  MQRC_OBJECT_ALREADY_EXISTS` error.  Kindly provide some suggestion.

Connect to MQ Manager:

```
mqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager(mqQueueManagerName);
```

Open Put Queue:

```
mqPutQueue = mqQueueManager.AccessQueue(mqRequestQueueName, MQC.MQOO_INQUIRE |
              MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
```

Opening the ReplyTo Queue generates the error when the second user tries to connect.  The First user's dynamic queue will be deleted when they disconnect.  That Second user is unable to connect, until the first user closes the application:

```
mqGetQueue = mqQueueManager.AccessQueue(mqModelQueueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED ,
   mqQueueManagerName, mqReplyQueueName, "");
```

Comment: Are you trying to create dynamic queues? This error happens only when you try to create a queue dynamically which already exist.  Check if mqRequestQueueName and mqModelQueueName are the same.

Comment: yes the Correct , i dont how To clear the Dynamic queue,here mqpreplyQueueName holds the dynamic queue name

Comment: mqRequestQueueName and mqModelQueueName  are different i  checked .problem with the Dynamic queue only if i give some other name its creating

Comment: Hi ,
    i solved Like For the Dynamic Queue Name mqReplyQueueName-> Each time it comes i randomly generated an new dynamic queue name

Comment: yes thats the intended design for dynamic queues. If you want more than one instance of application to get from the queue, I suggest go with permanent queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably specifying the dynamic queue name incorrectly.

To provide the greatest flexibility to developers, WebSphere MQ allows a choice between selecting the exact name you want for a dynamic queue or letting WebSphere MQ generate unique names automatically.  If you want WebSphere MQ to generate the name for you, make sure the name you pass in is short enough to allow WMQ to append additional characters, and specify an asterisk as the last character in the `DynamicQName` field.  This is explained in the docs in a section called [*Creating Dynamic Queues*](http://ibm.co/PetwkF) which reads as follows:

You can specify the name of the dynamic queue that you create in three ways:

- Give the full name that you want in the `DynamicQName` field of the
  MQOD structure.
- Specify a prefix (fewer than 33 characters) for the
  name, and allow the queue manager to generate the rest of the name.
  This means that the queue manager generates a unique name, but you
  still have some control (for example, you might want each user to use
  a certain prefix, or you might want to give a special security
  classification to queues with a certain prefix in their name). To use
  this method, specify an asterisk (*) for the last non-blank character
  of the `DynamicQName` field. Do not specify a single asterisk (*) for
  the dynamic queue name.
- Allow the queue manager to generate the full
  name. To use this method, specify an asterisk (*) in the first
  character position of the `DynamicQName` field.

Based on the behavior you are describing, I'm guessing there's no asterisk in the name that you are passing to WMQ.  It therefore assumes you want to explicitly specify the name and does exactly what you specified, although perhaps not what you intended.

To get the behavior you expect, make sure the value you pass for `mqReplyQueueName` is a single asterisk (the '`*`' character), or is a string of less than 33 characters that ends with an asterisk.